# How can I separate a word into characters and show each character in a button?

Tags: android-studio, button, char

I have an array of words and I want to show each word divided by characters. Each character has to set Text of a different button, so each button has a character from the word.

String [] palabras = {"casa", "auto", "perro", "zapatilla", "condor", "correa", "gato", "alfombra"};

I need to divide each word from this array and show each character in a different button.

Comment: What have you tried so far and with what exacly you have a problem?

Comment: I have tried using split(""); but I didn't know how to save the result to show it on the button